# Package amazonaws.mobilehelper.config does not exist

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to manually integrate AWS DynamoDB to my Android project following the tutorial they provide.

At some point the tutorial says to add the following dependency to project's app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies go here ...

    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.2')
}
```

I did that, finished the tutorial, synced, rebuilt the project and 53 errors appeared. Hurray!

I solved some of these errors by adding the cognito, core, ddb and ddb-mapper jars to the project but this error is persistent one:

```
error: package com.amazonaws.mobilehelper.config does not exist
```

For some reason it cannot find the mobilehelper package. I'm using Android Studio

Any idea?

Comment: do you have AWS account and set up your AwsCredentials.properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using AWS Mobile Hub to integrate AWS DynamoDB to Android project. One of the first step in manual integration is to `Download the SDK and helper code`. You need to include the `MySampleApp/AWSMobileHelper` folder in your Android Studio project. This folder contains the pkg: `com.amazonaws.mobilehelper.config`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to project's app/build.gradle file:

compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'

compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.+'